# webrtc streaming wpf to browser

Tags: wpf, webrtc

Is it possible to stream a wpf/winforms application to a web browser?

User would think he is on a website but it's just a WPF/winforms application being streamed to the browser..

Downside is it's probably very costly resources (dedicated server sessions). I just need PAAS (not IAAS).

Greetings,

Flieks

Comment: Have you looked at XBAP?

Comment: Or Windows RemoteApp?

Comment: @GlenThomas thanks but 
XBAP  looks not maintained (.NET 3.0)
            ,probably requires plugin (it's xaml based)
            and probably needs adjustments to your code
RemoteApp  doesn't work on mac/linux
                    and doesn't run inside the browser (=minimal user setup)
i want to streams a WPF/winforms app into the browser, so the user thinks it's just a website.

Comment: A colleague of mine suggested the same idea some years ago, it took us only a few minutes to come to the conclusion that it was a terrible idea. If you are looking for something that works across all platforms and is primarily server-based then I would strongly recommend building a website.

Comment: Yes probably you are right. Just wanted to be sure. It will take a year extra to convert our application but then we are good for the future. Thanks

Comment: You could try porting it to Silverlight if it isn't too big, but that will be a big task too and comes with a number of limitations. Website is probably the way to go

Comment: thanks, we are going with javascript and websockets and stream the viewport of our big editing control to the browser. This way we can reuse our api (server side)